# Proof that the bootstrap realizations are iid

Tags: self-study, bootstrap, iid

Let $x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_n $ be the values of a random sample. A bootstrap sample $x_1 ^* ,x_2^*, \ldots, x_n^* $ is a random sample of $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ drawn with replacement.

My question is how can I show that the bootstrap sample values are iid with common cdf $\hat{F_n}$, the empirical cdf of $x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_n $? Thank you.

Comment: To many people (e.g. https://www.scss.tcd.ie/Rozenn.Dahyot/453Bootstrap/2007Bootstrap02.pdf), what you are asking to show is the very definition of a bootstrap sample!  It appears, then, that you are starting with a different definition.  *What is it?*

Comment: @whuber Can I merely say that since all $x_{i}^* s $ are sampled with replacement, then they are equilikely and end of story?

Comment: Yes; this appears to be a question about how to translate English into mathematics :-).  "Drawing" one value $x^{*}_i$ from $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ is just a more descriptive way of asserting the CDF of $x^{*}_i$ is the empirical CDF ($\hat{F}$) and "with replacement" means all values $x^{*}_j$ are drawn independently from the same CDF.

Comment: @whuber Follow-up question. I can easily see that $E(x_{i}^*)=\bar{x}$. But how could I show that the variance of $x_i^*$ is $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i}-\bar{x})^2$ ? My try is $V(x_i^*)=E(x_i ^{*2}) -\bar{x}^2 $ and then after noticing that $x_i^*$ is one of the $x_i 's$, the expectation is the same and thus I can replace it with that expectation which gives me the required formula. Thanks.

Comment: Once again there is an issue of where you are starting from: the mean squared difference from the mean is (one) *definition* of a variance, implying you are starting from a different definition. After contemplating that, consider editing your question to state what you are assuming at the outset and what you want to prove.

Comment: @whuber But did you notice that in the variance formula I need to prove, the variance is given by the squared difference of $x_i 's$ from their mean rather than the $x_i^*$ ? That is the tricky part.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11741/discussion-between-whuber-and-ioannis)

Comment: @whuber I think that what I am supposed to note there is that an $x_i^*$ is part one of the $x_i s$ and thus it has the variance of such.